# Why is it so hard to use gcloud commands from my host computer instead of the gcloud interactive shell?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Maybe I'm just a bit confused, but basically I'm trying to establish my workflow with using the `gcloud` cli through my own host (Mac) terminal rather than the provided gcloud interactive shell.

I'm authenticating with an IAM member by running:

`gcloud auth login`

It takes me to the Google Cloud login page, which I successfully authenticate with and then I get the following in my shell:

```
You are now logged in as [MY_EMAIL@gmail.com].
Your current project is [myproperty-1537056464248].  You can change this setting by running:

  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

After this, I try to issue the following command:

```
gcloud container clusters create somename
```

And I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=Project "myproperty-1537056464248" has no network named "default".
```

My IAM user has the following roles:

- `Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin`
- `Owner`

All I want to do is avoid using the gcloud interactive shell so I can:

1. Create clusters through the command line
2. Push docker builds to the Google Container Registry
3. List clusters
4. Create pods
5. etc...

But these IAM policies aren't really working how I expect.

Should I be using a service account instead?

Comment: From the SDK, re-check that you're using the last version "$ gcloud components update";  the error message was prompted maybe it couldn't find the "default" network on that current project, so you can try eg: "$ gcloud container clusters create test-cluster --num-nodes=3 --subnetwork=default" ...make sure point out the network-name created. Regarding the permission using the IAM on your project you can restrict/allow action by roles.. on your case I think the Owner rol is allows to issue all commands in the project. more over: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles

Comment: @J.Rojas thanks, this helped me realize that Google had my old (deleted) project set (which turned out to be the issue). So I updated that, but now I have a new issue when creating clusters of: `ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.networks.get' permission for 'projects/myproperty-237306/global/networks/default'.` even though I assigned the following roles: `Compute Admin, Compute Instance Admin (v1), Compute Network Admin, Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin, Editor, Owner` to the IAM user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hit two distinct errors:

1. The 1st error message says your project is missing the 'default' network.

You can check your project's networks with:

```
$ gcloud compute networks list
NAME     SUBNET_MODE  BGP_ROUTING_MODE  IPV4_RANGE  GATEWAY_IPV4
default  AUTO         REGIONAL
```

If you create a fully new project it should have a 'default' network.

Or you can specify an existing network with:

```
gcloud container clusters create somename --network=put-existing-network-here
```

2. The 2nd error is lack of permission 'compute.networks.get' in the project.

You can verify the actual roles in the project by using 'gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID'. Look for the role 'owner' for your IAM user, like this:

```
$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID
- members:
  - user:username@somedomain.com
  role: roles/owner
```

Comment: Turns out, gcloud had set my default project to my OLD project (the one I deleted days ago), and I just updated it to be set using the new one. 

Unfortunately, now when I create the clusters using this command: `gcloud container clusters create somename --network=default` I get this dreaded: `ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.networks.get' permission for 'projects/myproperty-237306/global/networks/default'.`

Comment: ju, there is something with the permission roles in the project; so your user has owner role, this's something unexpected (I think), however if I were you I should set using one of the roles described by google doc (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam) where has the 'compute.networks.get' permission needed on your case. eg: roles/compute.instanceAdmin. if it doesn't work you can open a internal case with them. IAM roles are a little bit tricky in the beginning.

Comment: @bob_cobb answer updated to include how to check iam roles for the project.

Comment: @Everton this actually helped me debug my issue further. Ultimately, I had to re-enable the service account, because at some point it got deleted. Thank you! https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#gke_service_account_deleted#restore_service_account

Answer (score 3):

New projects should come with a network called `default` but I somehow ended up with one that didn't have a any networks at all (which caused me to see the same error).

After creating one...

```
gcloud compute networks create default
```

I was able to create a GKE cluster like so:

```
gcloud container clusters create mattscluster --zone us-west2 --machine-type e2-standard-2
```